# Visualising data from glm/ glmer

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, data-visualization, error-message

Sorry if this question sounds very amateurish, but I am completely new to R and this website. So, I have a data set with counts of infected organisms as a response variable (for three different species) and 5 different predictor variables. The infected organism count data is from over 200 surveys where they did not collect the same number of organisms each time. Some variables were measured for the entire site (constant across all surveys), some are unique to each survey.

An example of how the data is structured:

[image]

So, I used the `cbind()` when creating the glm to account for the fact that this is proportion data.

```r
Disease_glm <- glm(cbind(n_infected, not_infected) ~ 
    var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5, family = "binomial", 
    data = Disease)
```

Then I used DHARMa to test for dispersion

```r
testDispersion(simulateResiduals(Disease_glm))
```

There was significant overdispersion so I created a unique ID for each survey

```r
Disease$survey_ID = c(1:dim(Disease)[1])
```

So the data now has a survey ID column tucked in at the end.

And then I used it as a random effect in my model:

```r
Disease_glmer <- glmer(cbind(n_infected, not_infected) ~ 
    var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 + (1|survey_ID), 
    family = "binomial", data = Disease)
```

This solved the overdispersion issue.

I just wanted to visualise the results for each species. How much impact does var1, var2 ... have on infection numbers in Species 1, for instance.

This is where major issues started cropping up. At first, I tried

```r
ggplot(data =Disease D) + 
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = var1+var2+var3+var4+var5, 
    y = (cbind(n_infected, not_infected)),  color = species))
```

But I got the error message "Error in `check_aesthetics()`: ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (225): y"

Since I am so new that I do not know how to interpret this at all, I just abandoned it and tried a different route:

```r
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
with(Disease, plot((cbind(n_infected, 
    not_infected)) ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5, pch=16, 
    color = MergedChytrid$species))
curve(exp(cbind(1,x)%*%coef(chytrid_glmer)), add=T, col = "goldenrod", 
    lwd=3)
```

The first bit gives me the error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' 
lengths differ
```

Trying to run the curve function gave me:

```
Error in cbind(1, x) %*% coef(chytrid_glmer) : requires 
numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

Could you please help me understand where I am going wrong? It seems like such a basic thing. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't think the plotting functions are as flexible as glm with understanding formulae.
Are `n_infected` and `not_infected` vectors of counts? What about var1..5?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I'm so sorry, I'm not a 100% sure what you mean, but they're all representing columns of continuous variables in my csv?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your use of a random effect model. You create a group for each observation and use that as a random effect... I don't see the reason for doing that.

Regarding the overdispersion, you could account for it by using the `quasibinomial` distribution family. Maybe an alternative could be to use the negative binomial distribution (`glm.nb` in MASS package) and set `n_surveyed` as offset term.

> How much impact does var1,var2... have on infection numbers in Species 1, for instance.

It seems to me that you should have `Species` in your model interacting with each of the 5 variables (perhaps also `Area` should be in the model). Like:

```
Disease_glm <- glm(cbind(n_infected, not_infected) ~ var1*Species + var2*Species + var3*Species + var4*Species + var5*Species + Area, family = "quasibinomial", data = Disease)
```

Then the table of coefficents (from `summary(Disease_glm)`) will give you the estimates for each species and `var` relative to the intercept term. It may be difficult to read and the package [emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) could be handy.

Comment: First, thank you SO much. I was trying to say that each survey was a fixed effect. But in hindsight, I think it would make more sense to say each Area (these are protected area/ national park sort of places) is a fixed effect. Your solution was great, in that it fixed the overdispersion issue so that there is no need for quasibinomial or glmer. However, it also took one of the species (the one starting with a letter further up the alphabet) as the intercept. So I ended up getting usable data for the other two species only, from the summary. But I will have a look at the emmeans output, too.

Comment: Your "species" is a factorial predictor. That's why the models chooses one of its 3 levels as the reference category to which it compares the two others. This is the way regression coefficients for categorical predictors are modeled. You can run the analysis again with a different reference category to be able to compare the remaining two groups with each other. The command "relevel" does this handily with lmer, not sure about glm though.

Comment: There is no need to refit the model with different reference categories - it's an option but it's unnecessary and it could be cumbersome. All those models would actually be the same. The emmeans package has a number of functions to facilitate this sort of investigation.